# spring batch remains in EXECUTING

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I created a job which uses reader of type
`org.springframework.batch.item.database.HibernateCursorItemReader` to execute a query.

The problem is database connection in this case is hitting connection limit (I have a oracle error `ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found`) and, surprisingly, I noticed `exit_code=EXECUTING and status=STARTED on BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION table.`

If I run again the job it will respond  `"A job execution for this job is already running"` and if I issue `-restart` on this task, it complains with message `"No failed or stopped execution found for job".`

How does spring batch manages these fatal failure situations? Do I have to remove these execution information manually or is there a reset option?
Thank you for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the current release of Spring Batch (2.2.0) doesn't appear to have an out of the box solution for this situation.  as discussed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17336959/batchjob-batchjob-still-running-when-is-server-stopped), 'manual' intervention in the database may be required.  alternatively, if this is a particular job that is hanging (that is, you know the job name), you can do the following as well;

- use the `JobExplorer.findRunningJobExecutions(jobName)`
- go through the list of executions and 'fail' them (`JobExecution.upgradeStatus(BatchStatus.FAILED)`)
- save the change using `JobRepository.update(jobExecution)`

Answer (score 0):

Just an FYI why this problem of connection limit occurs when using a CursorItemReader (JDBCCursorItemReader or HibernateCursorItemReader)

The cursorItemReader opens a separate connection even if there is already a connection opened for the transaction (Reader -> Processors -> Writer). So, each step execution needs two connections even if it is in a single transaction and hitting the same db. This causes the connection bottleneck and so the number of db connections should be double the number of threads configured in thread pool to execute the steps in parallel.
This can also be resolve if you provide a separate connection to your CursorReader.

JdbcPagingItemReader is another implementation of ItemReader which uses the same connection opened for the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Update batch tables with FAILED status in DB

**-- batch_step_execution**

```
UPDATE batch_step_execution
SET
    end_time = sysdate,
    last_updated = sysdate,
    status = 'COMPLETED',
    exit_code = 'FAILED'
WHERE
    step_execution_id IN (
        SELECT
            step_execution_id
        FROM
            batch_step_execution bse
        WHERE
                1 = 1
            AND status NOT IN ( 'COMPLETED', 'FAILED' )
            OR exit_code NOT IN ( 'COMPLETED', 'FAILED' )
    );
```

**-- batch_job_execution**

```
UPDATE batch_job_execution
SET
    end_time = sysdate,
    last_updated = sysdate,
    status = 'COMPLETED',
    exit_code = 'FAILED'
WHERE
    job_execution_id IN (
        SELECT
            bje.job_execution_id
        FROM
            batch_job_execution bje
        WHERE
                1 = 1
            AND ( status NOT IN ( 'COMPLETED', 'FAILED' ) )
            OR ( exit_code NOT IN ( 'COMPLETED', 'FAILED' ) )
    );
```