# Single job execution across multiple servers

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-batch

I have setup where multiple servers run a `@Schedule` which run a spring batch job that sends out emails to users. I want to make sure that only one instance of this job is ran across multiple servers.

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348062/spring-batch-remains-in-executing) question
I have implemented some logic to see if its possible to solve this using only spring batch.

To run a job I created a helper class `JobRunner` with the following methods:

```
public void run(Job job) {
    try {
        jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
    } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException e) {

        // Check if job is inactive and stop it if so.
        stopIfInactive(job);

    } catch (JobExecutionException e) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The `stopIfInactive` method:

```
private void stopIfInactive(Job job) {
    for (JobExecution execution : jobExplorer.findRunningJobExecutions(job.getName())) {
        Date createTime = execution.getCreateTime();

        DateTime now = DateTime.now();

        // Get running seconds for more info.
        int seconds = Seconds
                .secondsBetween(new DateTime(createTime), now)
                .getSeconds();

        LOGGER.debug("Job '{}' already has an execution with id: {} with age of {}s",
                job.getName(), execution.getId(), seconds);

        // If job start time exceeds the execution window, stop the job.
        if (createTime.before(now.minusMillis(EXECUTION_DEAD_MILLIS)
                .toDate())) {

            LOGGER.warn("Execution with id: {} is inactive, stopping",
                    execution.getId());

            execution.setExitStatus(new ExitStatus(BatchStatus.FAILED.name(),
                    String.format("Stopped due to being inactive for %d seconds", seconds)));

            execution.setStatus(BatchStatus.FAILED);
            execution.setEndTime(now.toDate());

            jobRepository.update(execution);
        }
    }
}
```

And then the jobs are ran by the following on all servers:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${email.cron}")
public void sendEmails() {
    jobRunner.run(emailJob);
}
```

Is this a valid solution for a multiple server setup? If not, what are the alternatives?

**EDIT 1**

I've did a bit more testing - setup two applications which run a `@Schedule` every 5 seconds that initiates a job using the helper class I created. It seems that my solution does not resolve the problem. Here is the data from `batch_job_execution` table that is used by spring batch:

```
 job_execution_id | version | job_instance_id |       create_time       |       start_time        |        end_time         |  status   | exit_code | exit_message |      last_updated       | job_configuration_location
------------------+---------+-----------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+-------------------------+----------------------------
             1007 |       2 |               2 | 2016-08-25 14:43:15.024 | 2016-08-25 14:43:15.028 | 2016-08-25 14:43:16.84  | COMPLETED | COMPLETED |              | 2016-08-25 14:43:16.84  |
             1006 |       1 |               2 | 2016-08-25 14:43:15.021 | 2016-08-25 14:43:15.025 |                         | STARTED   | UNKNOWN   |              | 2016-08-25 14:43:15.025 |
             1005 |       2 |               2 | 2016-08-25 14:43:10.326 | 2016-08-25 14:43:10.329 | 2016-08-25 14:43:12.047 | COMPLETED | COMPLETED |              | 2016-08-25 14:43:12.047 |
             1004 |       2 |               2 | 2016-08-25 14:43:10.317 | 2016-08-25 14:43:10.319 | 2016-08-25 14:43:12.03  | COMPLETED | COMPLETED |              | 2016-08-25 14:43:12.03  |
             1003 |       2 |               2 | 2016-08-25 14:43:05.017 | 2016-08-25 14:43:05.02  | 2016-08-25 14:43:06.819 | COMPLETED | COMPLETED |              | 2016-08-25 14:43:06.819 |
             1002 |       2 |               2 | 2016-08-25 14:43:05.016 | 2016-08-25 14:43:05.018 | 2016-08-25 14:43:06.811 | COMPLETED | COMPLETED |              | 2016-08-25 14:43:06.811 |
             1001 |       2 |               2 | 2016-08-25 14:43:00.038 | 2016-08-25 14:43:00.042 | 2016-08-25 14:43:01.944 | COMPLETED | COMPLETED |              | 2016-08-25 14:43:01.944 |
             1000 |       2 |               2 | 2016-08-25 14:43:00.038 | 2016-08-25 14:43:00.041 | 2016-08-25 14:43:01.922 | COMPLETED | COMPLETED |              | 2016-08-25 14:43:01.922 |
              999 |       2 |               2 | 2016-08-25 14:42:55.02  | 2016-08-25 14:42:55.024 | 2016-08-25 14:42:57.603 | COMPLETED | COMPLETED |              | 2016-08-25 14:42:57.603 |
              998 |       2 |               2 | 2016-08-25 14:42:55.02  | 2016-08-25 14:42:55.023 | 2016-08-25 14:42:57.559 | COMPLETED | COMPLETED |              | 2016-08-25 14:42:57.559 |
(10 rows)
```

I also tried the method provided by @Palcente, I've got similar results.

Comment: Can you explain what is not working in the above case ? Do you mean multiple executions of the same job is being run at the same time ?

Comment: Yes, both servers start the same job at the same time, even though if its still running/starting on one of the nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Integration's latest release added some functionality around distributed locks.  This is really what you'd want to use to make sure that only one server fires the job (only the server that obtains the lock should launch the job).  You can read more about Spring Integration's locking capabilities in the documentation here: http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/

Comment: I'm unable to find any examples on documentation or spring-integration-samples (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples) project which show this functionality using java-config. At the moment I'm thinking of creating a simple lock table.